# Query with IN and row constructor with dapper

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper

With MySQL it is possible to query two columns with the IN operator like this:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE (a, b) IN ((1,2), (3,4))
```

See docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in

See also: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34266/selecting-where-two-columns-are-in-a-set

I would like to create this query with dapper. How can I do that?

My attempt:

```
connection.QueryAsync("SELECT * FROM test where (a, b) IN @params)", new { params = myList.Select(x => (x.a, x.b)) });
```

But this resulted in a `NotSupportedException` with the message `The member  of type <>f__AnonymousType18'2[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]] cannot be used as a parameter value`.

Comment: Might be helpful to post the full exception call stack; http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: This also seems like it might be a Dapper feature request, so you might want to post here: https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper.Contrib/issues